# Не устанавливается Django (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Tags: python, windows, django

Здравствуйте. Ставлю django на windows с python 2.7/3.3 (ставлю на 2.7). Открываю консоль, пишу

```
python setup.py install
```

И получатся вот такая штука ссылка - такого, как мне кажется, быть не должно. Что может быть причиной этому?

[image]

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Причиной этому может быть **Python 3.3**

Comment: да, в этом и была проблема, спасибо Вам большое